# Avoiding Android ListView from recycling until after animation

Tags: android, listview

I have some animation going on for items in a listview, and I don't want the listview item to be recycled until after the animation is finished. Is there any way to do this for APIs lower than 16?

Answer (score 1):

If you really have the case needs to keep the view from recycle, look at this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MIfSxgsHIs

1. use view property animator (keep the view from recycle until the animation is done):

   view.animate().setDuration(1000).alpha(0).withEndAction(new Runnable() {

   ```
   @Override
   public void run() {
     …
     view.setAlpha(1);
   }
   ```

   });

or

2.
set view transient state, it will not be recycled until clear its transient state:

```
view.setHasTransientStat(true);
view.setHasTransientStat(false);
```

Comment: Use Method 1. It is available from API 12. But I would prefer RecyclerView over listview today.